# UIColorPickerViewController drag dismiss not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

If a user drags down the `UIColorPickerViewController`, rather than hit the `(X)` button the `colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish` `UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate` delegate method isnt triggered.

Is this expected behaviour?

I want to wait until the modal is dismissed before updating the parent's UI

Comment: I agree that this does not seem like expected behavior.  At the least there should be a colorPickerViewCotrollerCancelled called or the did colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish should be called as well.  In addition I think the (X) icon should be changed to a checkbox.  I've submitted a feedback case to Apple today regarding the issue.  Please submit as well.